# Client Creation using WebSocketSharpAPI - C#

Tags: c#, webclient, httpserver, websocket-sharp

Hi StackOverflow Members,

I have created an HTTP server using WebsocketsharpAPI https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp.
Here I have created an HTTP address = "http://localhost:0001/MoviePage";

I am then, Initializing and creating the Httpserver and starting it under the
Subquery /MoviePage . Here to test if client is receiving data in first place, I am sending a string of movie name instead of movie object that I have

```
        Server.WebSocketServices[DisplayCollimationPort].Sessions.Broadcast("Spider Man 2");
```

The Server works without any issue. However, the issue is - I am not sure, How to use this
Websocketsharp API to Create a client and receive the sent string via a broadcast function from the server.

The examples are given only harnessing(or maybe I am missing something) the Websocketserver and Websocket class for the Server and Client in the examples provides.

Now since my address is an HTTP one and not a (ws or wss) (WebSocket) one, I would like to know if I can still use this websocketsharp API to implement a client to fetch string sent in this URL and access it. This is also because I would not be able to receive the information from httpserver with Websocket class.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance !!